# Drawing defects in the plane surrounding lattice squares

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, mathematical-physics, riemann-surfaces, visualization

Localized curvature of a surface that is otherwise flat is sometimes called a *curvature defect.* If we put a cube on a table and cover it with a table cloth and wrap it with three rubber bands, the top four corners are called −90° defects and the bottom four corners are called +90° defects.

Here is my question: How does one visualize and draw the two kinds of defects in the plane surrounding lattice squares so that we can use the drawing to explain the two terminologies?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you would like to see? For example, you could show curvature in the plane with distortions like those in "Fig 3" in https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYY2B.png (image from this patent https://www.google.com/patents/US5339121)